# Is it possible to wildcard a host_vars directory?

Tags: ansible, vmware, ansible-inventory

Long story short: I've established a home-lab where I use Ansible with VMware dynamic inventory plugin.
To distinguish between the different VMs the plugin adds the uid to the hostname, example: `unique-test-vm_2612e560x1284x8457e115`. This makes it hard for me to create host_vars directories because I constantly have to run `ansible-inventory -i ...` and copy the inventory name.

**Question**
Is it possible to create "wildcarded" host_vars directories without including the uid in the directory name? Meaning the name of the directory would be `unique-test-vm` instead of `unique-test-vm_2612e560x1284x8457e115`.

Comment: Just to be sure. To rephrase the question: All hosts `unique-test-vm_*` should share the variables in `host_vars/unique-test-vm`. Right?

Comment: Yes. Well... `unique-test-vm` is only one virtual machine. I could of course create `group_vars` for every host needing unique variable, but then again I need to create a tag in VMware and assign it...

Comment: Shall all files in the directory `unique-test-vm` be shared by all `unique-test-vm_*` hosts?

Comment: Files in `unique-test-vm` should only be used by unique-test-vm_2612e560x1284x8457e115. As I stated in my previous comment I can use `group_vars`. In other words: Let's say I have two virtual machines: `test-vmA_xxx` and `test-vmB_xxx`. Each of these virtual machines have their own unique variable. `test-vmA_xxx` has `variableA: true` and `test-vmB_xxx` has `variableB: false`. Creating a `group_vars` for each virtual machines would be overkill. Meaning `host_vars` makes sense

Comment: What directory shall be used for a host, e.g. `unique-test-vm_123` ?

Comment: VMware does not allow multiple virtual machines with the same name.
There cannot be two `unique-test-vm`, meaning the dynamic inventory plugin itself should be solved different.

Comment: Let me rephrase: VMware can have virtual machines with the same name as long they are in different folders. But for this case, let's say the names are **unique**

Comment: I see. Another workaround would be `include_vars`.

Comment: Not sure if that scales.

Comment: It does not. This is what is available. `VMWARE_INCLUDE_TAGS=True` and `group_vars` seems to be the [best option](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/43776) atm. There are other [enhancements](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/68393) wip.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it!
Looks like we hit the dead end. Anyways thank you for your time, Vladimir. Look forward to hear from you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to create "wildcard" *host_vars*. But, this use-case can be solved either by [*include_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/include_vars_module.html#include-vars-load-variables-from-files-dynamically-within-a-task) or by [*group_vars*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#organizing-host-and-group-variables). Mind the precedence of the variables. See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable).

---

**include_vars** (single host)

For example, let's have this inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
testX-vm_07
```

Let's create `host_vars`

```yaml
shell> cat host_vars/testX-vm/main.yml 
test_var: test var for hosts testX-vm_*
```

Then the playbook below reads the variables from the directory `host_vars/testX-vm`. Fit the parsing of the *inventory_hostname* to your needs

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: testX-vm_07
  tasks:
    - include_vars:
        dir: "{{ 'host_vars/' ~ my_vars_dir }}"
      vars:
        my_vars_dir: "{{ inventory_hostname.split('_').0 }}"
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml

PLAY [testX-vm_07] ****

TASK [include_vars] ****
ok: [testX-vm_07]

TASK [debug] ****
ok: [testX-vm_07] => 
  test_var: test var for hosts testX-vm_*
```

---

**group_vars** (multiple hosts)

For example, let's have this inventory

```bash
shell> cat hosts
testX-vm_01
testX-vm_02
testX-vm_03
testY-vm_01
testY-vm_02
testY-vm_03
```

Let's create `group_vars` that shall be shared by the hosts `testX-vm_*` and `testY-vm_*` respectively

```bash
shell> cat group_vars/testX_vm/main.yml
test_var: test var for testX_vm group
```

```bash
shell> cat group_vars/testY_vm/main.yml
test_var: test var for testY_vm group
```

Then the playbook below creates groups `testX_vm` and `testY_vm` in the first play and uses the groups in the second and third play. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - block:
        - add_host:
            name: "{{ item }}"
            groups: testX_vm
          loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    select('match', '^testX-vm_(.*)$')|
                    list }}"
        - add_host:
            name: "{{ item }}"
            groups: testY_vm
          loop: "{{ ansible_play_hosts_all|
                    select('match', '^testY-vm_(.*)$')|
                    list }}"
      run_once: true
  
- hosts: testX_vm
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var

- hosts: testY_vm
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i hosts pb.yml 

PLAY [all] ****
TASK [add_host] ****
changed: [testX-vm_01] => (item=testX-vm_01)
changed: [testX-vm_01] => (item=testX-vm_02)
changed: [testX-vm_01] => (item=testX-vm_03)

TASK [add_host] ****
changed: [testX-vm_01] => (item=testY-vm_01)
changed: [testX-vm_01] => (item=testY-vm_02)
changed: [testX-vm_01] => (item=testY-vm_03)

PLAY [testX_vm] ****
ok: [testX-vm_01] => 
  test_var: test var for testX_vm group
ok: [testX-vm_02] => 
  test_var: test var for testX_vm group
ok: [testX-vm_03] => 
  test_var: test var for testX_vm group

PLAY [testY_vm] ****
ok: [testY-vm_01] => 
  test_var: test var for testY_vm group
ok: [testY-vm_02] => 
  test_var: test var for testY_vm group
ok: [testY-vm_03] => 
  test_var: test var for testY_vm group
```

Comment: I would like to thank you for your suggestion Vladimir (https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/68393). I could solve my problem using the collection for vmware inventory   --> https://github.com/ansible-collections/vmware. Making it possible to get rid of the `UUID`.

Comment: im adopting your idea @Vladimir, for this.  Its a solution for setting vars when pulling hosts dynamically using aws_ec2 module.  I was looking for a solution for host_vars, hoping wildcard would work, but this is good enough.  I already have my vars on group_vars from when the inventory was static.

So im just adding the hosts: all play on the top of my playbook, adjusting regex search, wham done... Thanks!

Comment: this seems to be backfiring in that i need the group vars for the windows servers to connect, so when the hosts: all runs, its trying to authenticate to winrm/ssh and cant because it doesnt have access to whats on the group_vars.  catch22.

Comment: Any host can be a member of multiple hosts.  You don't have to connect in the first play. I added `gather_facts: false` to the play. If you have a problem open a question and make it [mre].